# Convert Data Class in R while importing in CSV

Tags: r, csv

I have csv file which has 6 column, out of which first four columns are character & other two are numeric.

But while importing this csv file all column get class get converted in factor. I want my first columns in  character & other two numeric how to do that?

I tried colClasses, transform but nothing is working

Comment: Add some code, so someone can help you.

Comment: Try `readr` package in R. Rstudio also has a GUI for the package where you can specify the class of each column of the CSV you are trying to import.

Answer (score 0):

Try `read.table(file = "file.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` (also works with `read.csv` / `read.csv2`)

Comment: above code is converting all coloum in caharcater i want something like this data <- read.csv('MIDANZ_CUSTOMER.csv', scan('data',sep=',',what=list, colClasses=c( rep('character',5),rep('numeric', 2))))

Comment: So, this doesn't work? `data <- read.csv(file  = "MIDANZ_CUSTOMER.csv", colClasses = c(rep("character", 4), rep("numeric", 2))`

Comment: nope, it throws this error Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, i think i have to install some packages not sure which one

Answer (score 0):

```
setClass("num.with.commas")
setAs("character", "num.with.commas", function(from) as.numeric(gsub(",","",from,fixed=TRUE)))

cl <- c(rep("character", 5), rep("num.with.commas",2))
data <- read.csv("Test.csv", colClasses = cl)
```